# Linked list from a file of words

Tags: c, linked-list, fgets

I'm struggling with a C issue and I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using a linked list to store words. When I execute the following:

```
list *myList = list_new();
list_append(myList,"Word_01");
list_append(myList,"Word_02");
list_append(myList,"Word_03");
list_append(myList,"Word_04");
list_print(myList);
```

Everything is OK and I get this output:

```
Word_01 -> Word_02 -> Word_03 -> Word_04 -> NULL
```

OK, now I take the words from a list stored in a file:

```
Word_01
Word_02
Word_03
Word_04
```

And execute this code:

```
const char *filename;
filename = "list";
list *myList2 = list_new();
FILE* file = NULL;
size_t size;
char line[256];
file = fopen(filename, "r");
if (file != NULL)
{
    printf("File opened.\n");
    while (fgets(line, 256, file) != NULL) {
        list_append(myList2, line);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
else {
    printf("Could not open file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
list_print(myList2);
```

Then I get the following output:

```
Word_04 -> Word_04 -> Word_04 -> Word_04 -> NULL
```

Can someone explain me why is this happening?

**Edit:**
Here is `list_append()`

```
void list_append(list *l, char *w) {
    word *new_word = malloc(sizeof(word));
    if (l == NULL || new_word == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new_word->_word = w;
    new_word->next = NULL;
    if (l->first->_word == "") {
        l->first = new_word;
    }
    else {
        word *temp = malloc(sizeof(word));
        temp = l->first;
        while(temp->next != NULL) {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new_word;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to **copy** the string inside `list_append()`. What you are doing now is saving the pointer value (the pointer to `line`). Each time the contents of `line` change all such pointers change the same way. Also don't forget `fgets()` keeps the trailing `'\n'`.

Comment: As pmg suggest issue is in list_append()

Comment: How to copy the `char[]` and not the pointer?

Comment: @AdityaNaidu : What do you mean?

Comment: @kh4r4: allocate enough memory (`new = malloc(strlen(input) + 1);`); test that succeeded (`if (!new) /* error */;`); copy the data (`strcpy(new, input);`). Of course you also need some way to free the memory when it is no longer needed.

Comment: The comparison `if (l->first->_word == "")` is probably not doing what you expect. It compares the pointers, not the characters. You may want to change that to `if (strcmp(l->first->_word, "") == 0)` or, easier, `if (*l->first->_word == 0)` ...

Comment: @pmg: Thank you very much. I have modified my code using your comments and now it works! (even the `'\n'` thing ^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments noted, you're handling the character strings incorrectly.  C-style strings are not things that you can equate with ==, or assign with =.  This is a C++ tutorial, but gives a good explanation of C-strings:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/66-c-style-strings/

Also check out the documentation for strcmp(), strcpy() and strlen().  I fixed the bits noted in the comments using those functions - note my comments:

```
void list_append(list *l, char *w) {
    word *new_word = malloc(sizeof(word));
    if (l == NULL || new_word == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //new_word->_word = w;
    // Allocate space and copy contents, not the pointer
    new_word->_word = malloc(strlen(w) + 1);
    strcpy(new_word->_word, w);

    new_word->next = NULL;
    //if (l->first->_word == "") {
    // Use strcmp() to compare the strings - returns 0 if they are equal
    if (strcmp(l->first->_word, "") == 0) {
        l->first = new_word;
    }
    else {
        word *temp = malloc(sizeof(word));
        temp = l->first;
        while(temp->next != NULL) {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    temp->next = new_word;
    }
}
```